# Setting date of datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

http://jsfiddle.net/t3n9p7kp/1/

I have a datepicker which is set up to select a whole week.  I have two buttons which are supposed to move the selected dates forward and backward a week.  The forward button works all the time, but the backward button only works if the month changes.  If the month does not change nothing happens.  The code is below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        var startDate;
        var endDate;

        var selectCurrentWeek = function() {
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')}, 1);
        }

        $('.week-picker').datepicker({
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
                endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
                var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
                $('.startDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings));
                $('.endDate').val($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings));
                $('.week-picker').val(" " + $.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings) + " - " + $.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings));

                selectCurrentWeek();
            },
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                var cssClass = '';
                if (date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                    cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
                return [true, cssClass];
            },
            onChangeMonthYear: function(year, month, inst) {
                selectCurrentWeek();
            }
        });

        $('.week-picker').datepicker("setDate", new Date());
        $('.ui-datepicker-current-day').click();

        $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').on('mousemove', null, function() { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
        $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').on('mouseleave', null, function() { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
    });

    $('#preWeek').click(function () {
        var startDate = $('.startDate').val();
        var newDate = new Date(startDate);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() - 7);
        $('.week-picker').datepicker("setDate", new Date(newDate));
        $('.ui-datepicker-current-day').click();
        return false;
    });

    $('#nextWeek').click(function () {
        var endDate = $('.endDate').val();
        var newDate = new Date(endDate);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
        $('.week-picker').datepicker("setDate", new Date(newDate));
        $('.ui-datepicker-current-day').click();
        return false;
    });
});
```

I cannot figure out why the date will not move backwards except when the month changes.

Comment: If you can add this code in fiddle, it would be easy to reply..

Comment: could you please implement this in a fiddle?.

Comment: Here is the fiddle:  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/t3n9p7kp/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `$('.ui-datepicker-current-day:first')` instead of `$('.ui-datepicker-current-day')` in the handlers for **next** and **prev** buttons will fix your issue. This was caused because you were clicking on 7 days of the week.

```
$('#preWeek').click(function () {
    var startDate = $('.startDate').val();
    var newDate = new Date(startDate);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() - 7);
    $('.week-picker').datepicker("setDate", new Date(newDate));
    $('.ui-datepicker-current-day:first').click();
    return false;
});

$('#nextWeek').click(function () {
    var endDate = $('.endDate').val();
    var newDate = new Date(endDate);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 1);
    $('.week-picker').datepicker("setDate", new Date(newDate));
    $('.ui-datepicker-current-day:first').click();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This is interesting.  With your change the previous button works, but the next button does not.  If I just make your change to the previous button and leave the next button the same, they both work.  Thanks.  I will mark this as the answer.  Here is the working fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/t3n9p7kp/6/

Comment: `$('.ui-datepicker-current-day:last').click();` Put this in the next button. That'll fix it. With out it every **next** click the `onselect` need to execute 8 times. Even though there is no functionality issue, its a bit 'unclean' don't you think? I updated fiddle.  http://jsfiddle.net/rejithrkrishnan/t3n9p7kp/11/

Comment: Thanks RRK.  That makes a lot of sense.  I appreciate your help.